# Can't run a Powershell command in a SQL Server Agent Job Step

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-agent

I tried with "Powershell" option and commands (both don't work):

```
Get-Item "*.csv" | Out-File "d:\tracking\$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd-hhmmss).txt"

"Get-Item """*.csv""" | Out-File """d:\tracking\$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd-hhmmss).txt""""
```

And tried with "CmdExec" option and command (it doesn't work):

```
powershell.exe -Command "Get-Item """*.csv""" | Out-File """d:\tracking\$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd-hhmmss).txt""""
```

But the last command runs ok on a separate cmd.exe window
and the following also runs ok inside the powershell:

```
Get-Item "*.csv" | Out-File "d:\tracking\$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd-hhmmss).txt"
```

They create a text file eg. "20220607-112233.txt" containing the directory listing of CSV files

However I can't get this command to work from within the Job Step
The step finishes with "Unable to run. Syntax error"

Comment: it's SQL Server 2019. May be this helps:  PowerShell -version 5.0 , says "Installed",  PowerShell -version 6.0, says "not installed".

Comment: I just replaced every double quotes by three quotes (except for the starting and ending ones) because I read somewhere that it could help. The two lines in the first code block, are expressions that I tried (one each time) with the option "Powershell" selected at the Job Step window. In addition, the second code block works perfect in a cmd.exe console, but it doesn't from within the Job Step

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution:

I created a batch (.bat file) with the code inside block 2:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Get-Item """*.csv""" | Out-File """d:\tracking\$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd-HHmmss).txt""""
```

(I only changed the hh for HH, for 24 hours based time)

Then, I configured the Job Step to run the bat file (setting the option "cmdExec")

That's all

I don't know what was going on, directory permissions were ok, the command of code block #2 above even works if I execute it with `xp_cmdshell`